# all variants of writing the sentences where "as" means "and so"

Tags: inversion, comparison, as

As far as I know, if in some sentence "*as*" means "*and so*" this sentence can be written both with inversion and without it. Could you check my examples on this topic please:

**(1a)** *John is from Canada, as Bill is*.
**(1b)** *John is from Canada, as is Bill*.
I think **(1a)** & **(1b)** are correct.

---

**(2a)** *Bob works at the factory, as his farther works*.
**(2b)** *Bob works at the factory, as his farther does*.
**(2c)** *Bob works at the factory, as does his farther*.
I think **(2a)**, **(2b)** & **(2c)** are correct.

**(2d)** *Bob works at the factory, as does work his farther*.
I think **(2d)** is also correct but probably less common.

---

**(3a)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as Bred wants*.
**(3b)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as Bred does*.
**(3c)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as does Bred*.
I think **(3a)**, **(3b)** & **(3c)** are correct.

**(3d)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as does want Bred*.
**(3e)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as Bred wants to leave*.
**(3f)** *Frank wants to leave early today, as does want to leave Bred*.
I think **(3d)**, **(3e)** & **(3f)** are also correct but probably less common.

---

Peter: *I said that*.
Sam:
**(4a)** *As I said*.
**(4b)** *As I did*.
**(4c)** *As did I*.
I think **(4a)**, **(4b)** & **(4c)** are correct.

**(4d)** *As did say I*.
I think **(4d)** is also correct but probably less common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only correct ones are (1a), (1b), (2b), (2c) - except that it's *father* - (3b) and (3c). *As does X* sounds much more formal than *as X does*.

Sam would probably reply "So did I", though (4b)  and (4c) are not actually incorrect.